# How can I override examples in openapi?

Tags: swagger, openapi

I have the response structure:

```yaml
responses:
  '200':
    description: OK
    content:
      application/json:
        schema:
          type: object
          properties:
            data:
              allOf:
              - { $ref: ../../components/schemas/Product.yaml }
              example:
                active: false
```

And the Product.yaml one:

```yaml
type: object
description: Product
properties:
  id:
    description: ID
    type: integer
    example: 1
  name:
    description: Name
    type: string
    example: 'fresh baguette'
  active:
    description: Is active
    type: boolean
    example: true
```

So I wanna override active example and when I do it like this:

```yaml
data:
  allOf:
  - { $ref: ../../components/schemas/Product.yaml }
  example:
    active: false
```

In redoc ui under the "Response samples" I see the only active property.

My question is how can I override an example of only active property without overriding each of product properties?

Comment: my openapi version is 3.0.2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no way to override an individual property value in an example. You need to provide the whole example:

```yaml
responses:
  '200':
    description: OK
    content:
      application/json:
        schema:
          type: object
          properties:
            data:
              $ref: ../../components/schemas/Product.yaml

          example:
            data:
              id: 1
              name: fresh baguette
              active: false
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a hack to override individual properties.

```
responses:
  '200':
    description: OK
    content:
      application/json:
        schema:
          allOf:
            - $ref: ../../components/schemas/Product.yaml
            - type: object
              properties:
                 active: 
                   example: false
```

If you have more properties to override, just keep adding to the object.

```
- type: object
  properties:
    name:
      example: "fresh croissant"
    active: 
      example: false
```

However, there is a problem with this method. If `active` was an array and you had defined it as `[ "true" ]` in `Product.yaml`, and you try to override it as an empty array in the response, it won't do that. It'll display it as `[ "true" ]`.